# Speech Recognition is Not Available on this Device.Do you want to install Google App to have Speech Recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am developing android project which has Voice Feature . I have used Google Speech. I am getting this popup. Speech Recognition is Not Available on this device. Do you want to install Google App to have Speech Recognition? If I give yes, it redirects me to play store, but already the app is available on the mobile. I don't know what to do for this. Please help me to figure it out.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
private void onRecordAudioPermissionGranted() {
final Activity activity = ConsoleActivity.this;
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //   progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    // linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try {
        // Speech.getInstance().stopTextToSpeech();
        Speech.getInstance().startListening(progress, this);
    } catch (SpeechRecognitionNotAvailable exc) {

        Utils.showSpeechNotSupportedDialog(this);
    } catch (GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException exc) {
        Utils.showEnableGoogleVoiceTyping(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android does not have classes like GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException. Your question is thus incomplete, e.g. what library are you using?

Comment: @Kaarel, I have used built-in library only **compile project(':speech')** this only i have used in gradle file. For calling speech I have used like this **Speech speech = Speech.getInstance();**

Comment: I doubt it's a built-in library...